# is it possible to get full line method uisng AST Parser?

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I want to ask, is it possible to get full line method using AST Parser in java file?

example:

```
public double getAverage(int[] data) {
}
```

i only get method name (`getAverage`) using `MethodDeclaration`, while i hope full line `(public double getAverage(int[] data) {`

The second question, how to read closing of the method ( `}` ) ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do that but you can get all the required information and build the string yourself.

You can use **MethodDeclaration.getModifiers()** to get the modifier information which will tell you whether it is public or private.

You can use **MethodDeclaration.getReturnType2().resolveBinding().getName()** to get the name of the return type

and **MethodDeclaration.parameters()** will give you information about parameters.

one more trick to do is : 
**String signature= MethodDeclaration.toString().split("{")[0];**

but this may not be an efficient way to do.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, i will try to combine all of mentioned above.